# Model derivative and transient policy

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have two questions:

1. In model derivative API tutorial, the Revit file was uploaded to a bucket using transient policy ([link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-roominfo4viewer/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/#step-1-create-a-bucket)). Knowing that transient is deleted after 24 hrs, does this apply to the source file only (Revit file) or also the transformed file (SVF2 file)? In other words, will I be able to access the model in the viewer after 24 hrs?
2. After initiating a translation, I was able to check status using manifest [endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/). However, I noticed if I try to check the next day, I get 404 Not found. Is this normal? If yes, how can I access the thumbnails urls?

Many thanks,

Comment: Could you share your base64 URN with me? So that I can help check  our backend log.

Comment: @EasonKang I sent it by email

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the retention policy that fits your workflow, `transient`, `temporary` & `persistent`, which is the best way to ensure you app works well.

That said, the retention policy applies to the seed file only, meaning that only the seed file gets deleted according to the retention policy. The translated assets will still be there if you manage to store the URN and access later. But calling the `GET Manifest` will always return **404** as the seed file was deleted.

Comment: Actually, I can still access the translated model but not GET Manifest